# I need event element to append div after this event element. With Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need event element to append div after this event element. With Locker Service.
It's Working using jQuery before activation Locker Service. But now i am not getting event target element.

I want to display a div after a button click.
I am using lightning.

Here is some code example:

**Component**

`<lightning:button variant="neutral" value="deleteMass" onclick="{!c.doSomething}" />`

**Component Controller**

```
doSomething: function(cmp, event){
   var myButton = $(event.target).closest("button");

   // appending a div after that button
   var tabbedDiv = $(".tabular-dropdown");
   tabbedDiv.insertAfter(pTarget);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery here. Perhaps you could include some more code?

Comment: Hope [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM event not working in lightning component namespace (eg: lightning:button or ui:button)

I just put a unique Id in its parent
And put a value tag in *lightning:button* eg:

```
<li id="1212__Button">
 <lightning:button variant="neutral" value="1212__Button" onclick="{!c.doSomething}" />
</li>
```

And then i got the value in controller using *event.getSource()* eg:

```
doSomething: function(cmp, event){
 var value = event.getSource().get("v.value");
 var targetBtn.append(tabbedDivHtml); = $('#'+ value);
 var tabbedDiv = $(".tabular-dropdown");

 // appending a div after that button
 targetBtn.append(tabbedDiv);
}
```

Comment: This answer for those who has enabled locker service